# How to get jobId that was submitted using Dataproc Workflow Template

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I have submitted a Hive job using Dataproc Workflow Template with the help of Airflow operator ([DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateInlineOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integration.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateInlineOperator)) written in Python. Once the job is submitted some name will be assigned as jobId (example: `job0-abc2def65gh12`).

Since I was not able to get jobId I tried to pass jobId as a parameter from REST API which isn't working.

Can I fetch jobId or, if it's not possible, can I pass jobId as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JobId will be available as part of `metadata` field in `Operation` object that is returned from Instantiate operation. See this [1] article for how to work with metadata.

The Airflow operator only polls [2] on the Operation but does not return the final Operation object. You could try to add a return to `execute`.

Another option would to be to use dataproc rest API [3] after workflow finishes. Any labels assigned to the workflow itself will be propagated to clusters and jobs so you can do a list jobs call. For example the filter parameter could look like: `filter = labels.my-label=12345`

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/debugging#using_workflowmetadata

[2] https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L1376

[3] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/list