# How to get job ID or result of airflow DataFlowJavaOperator()?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I am using DataFlowJavaOperator() in airflow(Cloud Composer). Is there any way to get ID of executed dataflow job in next PythonOperator task? I would like to use the job_id to call `gcloud` command to get job result.

```py
def check_dataflow(ds, **kwargs)
  # here I want to execute gloud command with the job ID to get job result.
  # gcloud dataflow jobs describe <JOB_ID>

t1 = DataFlowJavaOperator(
    task_id='task1'
    jar='gs://path/to/jar/abc.jar',
    options={
        'stagingLocation': "gs://stgLocation/",
        'tempLocation': "gs://tmpLocation/",
    },
    provide_context=True
    dag=dag,
 )

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    python_callable=check_dataflow,
    provide_context=True
    dag=dag,
)


t1 >> t2
```

Comment: I see that your `operator` is different, but see if you could take hints from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54557446/3679900)

Comment: One possible hint: write the id to a storage and let the following operator read from it.

Answer (score 2):

As it appears, the `job_name` [option](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py#L45) in the `DataFlowJavaOperator` gets overridden by the `task_id`. Job name will have the task as the prefix and append a random ID suffix. If you still want to have a Dataflow job name that is actually different from the task ID you can add hard-code it in the Dataflow Java code:

```java
options.setJobName("jobNameInCode")
```

Then, using the `PythonOperator` you can retrieve the job ID from the prefix (either the job name provided in code or otherwise the Composer task id) as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395692/6121516). Briefly, list jobs with:

```py
result = dataflow.projects().locations().jobs().list(
  projectId=project,
  location=location,
).execute()
```

and then filter by prefix where `job_prefix` is the `job_name` defined when launching the job:

```py
for job in result['jobs']:
  if re.findall(r'' + re.escape(job_prefix) + '', job['name']):
    job_id = job['id']
    break
```

The break statement is there to ensure we only get the latest job with that name, which should be the one just launched.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes, that's actually similar approach I am doing to retrieve job ID now. I noticed that airflow's task.id-<random alphanumeric> is assigned to dataflow's job name. So I am utilizing the task.id as job name prefix.

I didn't know there is `job_name` parameter for `DataFlowOperator`, so I just tried it, but it turned out that `job_name` is ignored and still task.id-<random alphanumeric> is used for dataflow job name, I don't know why.. Also according to airflow task log, parameter `job_name` will be deprecated in Airflow 2.0.

Comment: But once you know the job name the PythonOperator task works fine, right? Another approach would be to set job name in the Java code which I just tested and works (i.e. `options.setJobName("jobNameInCode");`).

Comment: Setting job name in the java works perfect! I added extra param like `customDataflowJobName` in the DataflowJavaOperator's option and catch and use it on java end. So now I am able to define unique jobname for every dataflow jobs and check those results in next operator. Thank for your help!

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I edited my answer so that it's self-contained

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and I finally found a proper solution.
First of all **DataFlowJavaOperator** is now deprecated and should be replaced with **BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator**.

To use the **BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator** you need to install the `apache-airflow-providers-apache-beam` python package.

My Airflow DAG does not really change. You only need to migrate it to **BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator**.

```
start_dataflow = BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator(
    task_id="start_dataflow",
    jar="gs://path/to/jar/abc.jar",
    pipeline_options={
        "gcpTempLocation": "gs://tmpLocation/"
    },
    job_class="",
    runner=BeamRunnerType.DataflowRunner,
    dataflow_config={
        "job_name": "my-dataflow-job"
    },
    dag=dag
)

bash_dataflow_job_id = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_dataflow_job_id",
    bash_command="echo {{task_instance.xcom_pull('start_dataflow')['dataflow_job_id']}}",
    dag=dag
)
```

Now to the most important change. The last line that you write to stdout needs to follow this regex pattern: `Submitted job: (?P<job_id_java>.*)|Created job with id: \[(?P<job_id_python>.*)\]`

Here you can find the source code: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/553fb1f2ed0dfd177b11e3cc5232b964360fac8b/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataflow.py#L57

My solution for java looks like this:

```
PipelineResult pipelineResult = pipeline.run(pipelineOptions);

String jobId;
Class<? extends PipelineRunner<?>> runner = pipelineOptions.getRunner();
if (runner.isAssignableFrom(DataflowRunner.class)) {
    jobId = ((DataflowPipelineJob) pipelineResult).getJobId();
} else {
    jobId = pipelineOptions.getJobName();
}

// Needs to be the last console output for Airflow to receive the Dataflow Job ID
System.out.println("Submitted job: " + jobId);
```